# Use .htaccess to Clean URL and Rewrite Same Query, without "Too Many Redirects"

Tags: .htaccess

A user requests the following URI:

`https://example.com/page.php?s=201903071830&e=201904192359&t=sampletitle`

I want to use .htaccess to rewrite a clean URI in the browser:

`https://example.com/sampletitle`

**And** I want to map the clean URI *back* to the original URI.

I tried the following .htaccess rules:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=201903071830&e=201904192359&t=sampletitle$
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/sampletitle? [R,L]
RewriteRule ^sampletitle\/?$ /page.php?s=201903071830&e=201904192359&t=sampletitle [L]
```

Expecting that the `[L]` flag would stop rule-processing, here's what I thought would happen:

1. User request original (complex) URI.
2. .htaccess redirects to /sampletitle; rule processing ends.
3. `RewriteCond` does *not* match, so first `RewriteRule` is skipped.
4. Second `RewriteRule` matches and rewrites; rule processing ends.

But instead, I receive "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS," presumably because .htaccess is stuck in rewrite-matching loop.

How can I use .htaccess to redirect incoming requests for the original URI and then rewrite the same query string?

Comment: You miss understood what the `L` flag means for rule processing. Yes, it indeed stops rule processing, _but only for that iteration_ ! The engine starts over again afterwards, since the URL got rewritten in the last iteration. And the next iteration redirects the request again leading to an endless redirection loop. Instead take a look at the `END` flag the apache rewrite module offers for this from version 2.4 onwards. Or implement a rewriting condition that breaks the rewriting loop as @JAnderson demonstrated below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your rules as is and change the second line like this :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=201903071830&e=201904192359&t=sampletitle$
RewriteRule !^page\.php https://example.com/sampletitle? [R,L]
RewriteRule ^sampletitle\/?$ /page.php?s=201903071830&e=201904192359&t=sampletitle [L]
```

The error happened because you match against `QUERY_STRING` so , both URIs, original URI and the one you Rewrited to internally , have same `QUERY_STRING` but diffrent `URI` and that why you should exclud a URI start with page.php in this `RewriteRule !^page\.php` line.

Comment: Both this solution and @j-anderson's work.  This solution is the most concise and provides and explanation; j-anderson's proposes the simplest/clearest modification to the original rule set.

Answer (score 1):

Edit, I see the issue with what I originally posted and what you're trying  to do. Give this a go:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=201903071830&e=201904192359&t=sampletitle$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/?page.php
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/sampletitle? [R,L]
RewriteRule ^sampletitle\/?$ /page.php?s=201903071830&e=201904192359&t=sampletitle [L]
```